# C# Customising Propertygrid

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I am modifying an existing application which uses a property grid to display the properties of a selected item from a third party control.  The selected item always inherits from an 'Item' object which contains a 'DataField' string property.

I need to modify the way which the propertygrid displays the child objects so that the user can select the data field from a list of values which will be populated from a collection on the parent form.

Is this possible with the propertygrid?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, maybe [How do you create a custom collection editor form for use with the property grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530074/how-do-you-create-a-custom-collection-editor-form-for-use-with-the-property-grid) could solve your problem.

Comment: That answers part of the question.  The other part is how do I use this editor with the propertygrid which is bound to a third party object.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Step 3)Tell the PropertyGrid to use the alternate editor. The change between this property and any other that is used in the PropertyGrid control is the [Editor] line.

```
[Description("The name or text to appear on the layout.")]
[DisplayName("Text"), Browsable(true), Category("Design")]
[Editor(typeof(StringArrayEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public string[] Text {get; set;}
```

it is part of this answer: [Is there a better StringCollection editor for use in PropertyGrids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303360/is-there-a-better-stringcollection-editor-for-use-in-propertygrids)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: That would work well if I was using my own custom objects but I have to use third party objects which I cannot edit.